# SSH through Reverse-Proxy in docker-compose doesn't work

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, gitea

Setting Up a Gitea instance with a reverse proxy (NGINX) in docker-compose works fine for me.
After logging in to the webapp creating repositories, changing settings, etc. works. Even cloning repositories via HTTPS works. However, cloning via SSH runs into

```
git clone git@localhost:martin/asd.git
Cloning into 'asd'...
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How do I make process on identifying the problem? The docker-compose logs only show

```
production_nginx | 172.22.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2020:20:40:41 +0000] "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3" 400 157 "-" "-"
```

which isn't helpful for me.

The code docker-compose file and my nginx config can be accesed via my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/zwoefler/Gitea-SetUp)

Docker-Compose.yml:

```
version: "2"

networks:
  reverseproxy:
  gitea:
    external: false

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: production_nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "22:22"
    networks:
      - reverseproxy  
  server:
    image: gitea/gitea:latest
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=Gitea
      - USER_UID=1000
      - USER_GID=1000
      - DB_TYPE=postgres
      - DB_HOST=db:5432
      - DB_NAME=gitea
      - DB_USER=gitea
      - DB_PASSWD=gitea
      - DOMAIN=localhost
      - SSH_DOMAIN=localhost
      - HTTP_PORT=80
      - SSH_PORT=22
      - SSH_LISTEN_PORT=22
    restart: always
    networks:
      - gitea
      - reverseproxy
    volumes:
      - gitea_data:/data
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    expose:
      - "3000"
      - "22"
    depends_on:
        - db

  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=gitea
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=gitea
      - POSTGRES_DB=gitea
    networks:
      - gitea
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data 

volumes:
  gitea_data: {}
  postgres: {}
```

nginx.conf

```
events {}
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://gitea_server_1:3000;
    }
  }
  server {
    listen 22;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://gitea_server_1:22;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. You repo is gone, or private, 2. Update your question with the config.

Comment: Updated the question. Added NGINX.conf and docker-compose.yml

Comment: 1. Try set the log config for nginx, `error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log info;`                        
 2. ngx_stream_core is the one,  defines groups of servers that can be referenced by the proxy_pass directive. From the docs >>   `upstream backend {
    hash $remote_addr consistent;

    server backend1.example.com:12345  weight=5;
    server backend2.example.com:12345;
    server unix:/tmp/backend3;

    server backup1.example.com:12345   backup;
    server backup2.example.com:12345   backup;
}

server {
    listen 12346;
    proxy_pass backend;
}`

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I have the same problem. I am hosting gitea via docker-compose with SWAG as my reverse proxy but ssh doesn't work..

Comment: I forgot about it. Wasn't needed for me. have you given @abestrad comment a chance?